# Adding a datetime to a datatable with the current datetime?

Tags: powershell, datatable

I'm trying to add a field to a datatable with the current datetime.  I want to add it here so that when I use another piece of code to create the table, it creates it as datetime (add-sqltable, for what it's worth).

```
#create the datatable
$quer = invoke-sqlcmd2 -serverinstance myservername -database "tempdb" -query "select @@servername as servername" -As 'DataTable' 
#now add the datetime field
$quer.columns.add("InsDate",[DateTime])
```

At this point I get stuck.  This doesn't work:

```
$quer | %{$_.InsDate = get-date}
```

I get this error message:

```
Exception setting "InsDate": "Unable to cast object of type
 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject' to type 'System.IConvertible'.Could
n't store <2/26/2013 11:26:23 AM> in InsDate Column.  Expected type is DateTime."
```

Changing the format doesn't work either.  Is there some way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$quer | %{[datetime]$_.InsDate = get-date}
```

or this:

```
$quer | %{$_.InsDate = [datetime](Get-Date)}
```

I don't have the ability to test your specific case, but I believe one of them should work.

Edit: Changed closing ')' to '}' in second to fix answer.

Comment: Tested both solutions successfully using @mbourgon query.

Comment: @ChadMiller Good to hear, I don't have access to any of our SQL servers, so I can't test his specific case.

Comment: Weird.  The first one works fine, but the second tells me I'm missing a closing bracket, even if I add one.  But the first one works. Thanks @Nick!

Comment: Duh on my part. First one works fine.  Replace the closing paren with a closing bracket on the second.  Thanks again.

Comment: @mbourgon Thank you for the correction, I have fixed the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround:

```
    $date = get-date 
    $quer | %{$_.InsDate = [DateTime]$date}
```

Found here:
[DateTime parsing in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488879/datetime-parsing-in-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm might be missing the obvious here, but can't you adjust your SQL query to just pull the datetime at the source?

Something like this:

```
select
@@servername as [servername],
GETDATE() as [DateTime]
```

That is probably what I would do, rather than fudging it in later! :D

Comment: Not always an option. Say, for instance, sp_blitz.  You could either modify it each time he comes out with a new version, but this is easier long-term.